# How to gulp-regex-replace only the first match?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-replace

Below is the content from project.json file. I want the first occurrence of 'version' value to be replaced.

```
{
  "title": "Project Title",
  "copyright": "Copyright Info",
  "description": "Project Description",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "buildOptions": {
    "xmlDoc": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  }
}
```

The below code using gulp-regex-replace changes all occurrences of version value to 1.0.1.

```
var targetVersion= "1.0.1";
gulp.task('replace', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./src/**/project.json'])
        .pipe(bom())
        .pipe(replace({ regex: '\\n\\s\\s\\"version\\"\\:\\s\\"([0-9a-zA-Z.-]+)\\"', replace: `${targetVersion}` }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'));
});
```

How can I make this code replace only the first occurrence of version value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gulp-regex-replace` plugin uses global match:
https://github.com/mikrofusion/gulp-regex-replace/blob/master/index.js#L31

Another similar plugin [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) accepts a custom regexp object:

```
replace(/__your_pattern__/, targetVersion);
```

Without the `g` modifier in the pattern, JS will only match the first occurrence.